# Files in Subfolders are missing in Plugins section (Unity 3d) when I generate Xcode project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have added a Subfolder (Plugins/iOS/Subfolder) in project section. When I generate Xcode project the files in the Subfolder are missing. Why is this happening? Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Unity documentation site says:

> Note: subfolders are currently not supported.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

Comment: As long as I'm concerned, you can't deploy for iOS on Windows http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/198938/ios-games-development-on-windows.html

Comment: Yes. I work for both iOS and Android applications. I am talking about Android now.

Comment: Deploying for Android is quite different and seems it doesn't have this limitation http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Unity 5 supports subfolders as you desired, although their docs (as of writing) still say that this is unsupported. Posting this answer for anyone still on Unity 4 that might need a reason to upgrade.